# How to integrate fontawesome icons in mpdf in codeigniter?

Tags: html, css, codeigniter, mpdf

I have pdf generation code which I had written. When the pdf is being downloaded, there are some font awesome icons present in the pdf. It is not visible. I have tried some solutions. I have placed `fontawesome-webfont.ttf` in `mpdf/ttfonts`. After this I have written some codes in `fontvariables` in `mpdf/src/`:

```
'fontdata' => [
            
            "fontawesome" => [
                'R' => "fontawesome-webfont.ttf",
            ],
      ];
```

After this, I have written some code in the pdf generation part like :

```
$mpdfConfig = array(
            'mode' => 'utf-8', 
            'format' => 'A4-L',
            'orientation' => 'P',
            'default_font_size' => 10,
             'default_font' => 'Arial',
            'margin_top' => 17,    
             'margin_bottom' => 23,   
            //'tempDir' => '/tmp'
        );
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf($mpdfConfig);
    $mpdf->curlAllowUnsafeSslRequests = true;
   
   $stylesheet = '.fa-long-arrow-right { font-family: fontawesome; }';

    $html = $this->load->view('temp/'.$date.'/stream_finder_'.$exam_id.'_'.$uid,$data,true);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
    $mpdf->Output('Stream-finder-report.pdf', 'D');
```

In the html page,

```
 <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true" style="left: 6px;position: absolute;font-size: 20px;color: #07bb7b;"></i>
```

But in the pdf generated, the `fa-long-arrow-right` is not visible. Can anyone suggest how to correct this ?

Answer (score 0):

Setting a font family to an empty `<i>` by its definition can not output anything. Either:

Write the character `&#xf178;` that in Font Awesome is an arrow right, directly into HTML as an entity

```
<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true" style="...">&#xf178;</i>
```

Or:

Alter your CSS to output the character by the `content` property. Note that setting a fixed size for the `:before` pseudoelement may be necessary.

```
.fa-long-arrow-right:before {
  content: "\f178";
}
```